# PostAsync does not add querystring parameters

Tags: c#, api, post

I have a simple piece of software: I need to send a POST request to a  Web API with parameters.

So I use the following piece of code:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = "http://localhost:51074" })
{

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
                     {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", param1),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param2", param2),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param3", param3)
                     });

    string uri = "/api/Authenticate";
    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);

}
```

But whatever I try, the querystring parameters are not added to my request.
and I receive a 400 - Not Found error.

I have no clue why the parameters are not added.
If I just manually add the parameters to my uri, like :

```
string uri = "/api/Authenticate?param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3";
```

PostAsync works fine.

This drives me crazy. I hope someone has the solution.

I need to send an url as a parameter, that is why I need to use FormUrlEncodedContent

Comment: As its name implies (`FormUrlEncodedContent`), it is sent in the body of the request, not in url.

Comment: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Comment: thank you for the link; just what I needed. how can I upvote your comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting the error because your `Post` method of your Web Api is not expecting a complex type (`System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent`).  It is expecting a **string**. I'm guessing your Web Api method currently looks something like this:

```
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }
```

You should change it to be something like

```
    public void Post([FromBody]System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent value)
    {

    }
```

That way it will know which type to expect.

Comment: Hmmm,yes this seems to be the case. Thank you. and the above posters as well. I actually need multiple parameters to pass to my Web API method(s), the site posted by Eser handles just that.

Comment: I found another solution by using a JObject parameter in my Web API as described here : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods